# Is it appropriate to have different layers of Publishers for different subscribers?

Tags: swift, combine

Is it acceptable for a pipeline of publishers to have consumers subscribe to the different parts of the chain?

In theory the subscribers can do processing and filtering in its own pipeline. But I find that having a 'ready made' publisher makes it easy for the consumer. I see that this is not the pattern generally used for Combine. Is there a downside to this that I am missing?

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class Publisher {
    var rootPublisher = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].publisher
    var evenPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>

    init () {
        evenPublisher = rootPublisher.filter { num in num % 2 == 0 }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

class Consumer {
    let publisher = Publisher()
    func numbers () {
        publisher.rootPublisher.sink { int in
            print(int)
        }
    }
    func evenNumbers() {
        publisher.evenPublisher.sink { int in
            print(int)
        }
    }
}

Consumer().numbers()
Consumer().evenNumbers()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for a pipeline of publishers to have consumers subscribe to the different parts of the chain

The problem is that that's a completely toy example. In real life, you would discover that you would not be "sharing" the same ultimate publisher in any meaningful sense, because your `rootPublisher` is a *struct*.

It is perfectly legal for a publisher (meaning any portion of the head of the pipeline) to have more than one subscriber, but unless you say `share` (or `multicast`), it becomes two separate publishers.

> But I find that having a 'ready made' publisher makes it easy for the consumer. I see that this is not the pattern generally used for Combine

That's not true. Vending a complex opaque publisher (meaning the head of a pipeline) is quite standard. A data task publisher, for example, is something like a Deferred Future plus a Map even though you can't see that. The whole point is that you get to make up and vend your own publisher made up for the publisher-operator pieces you are given (or you can write your own).

Comment: See https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsSplitters/operatorssplitters.html and the next two pages (on `share` and `multicast`) as well.